# PubSub between Java and .Net

Tags: java, .net, nservicebus, esb, publish-subscribe

Is there a good free service bus for .Net that allows subscriptions from Java clients?
I'm working with NServiceBus and I like the fluent API and the simplicity, but it doesn't support Java clients or WCF integration for web-service based connections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus has builtin WCF support for receiving incoming commands. See the WcfIntegration sample that comes with the NSB download.

Answer (score -1):

NServiceBus is a great tool for pub-sub and is very easy to configure:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/